# Modify gform_other_choice_value for specific form and specific field in Gravity Forms

Tags: functions, filters, plugin-gravity-forms

I am looking to change the "other" text for a single specific field on a specific form in Gravity Forms.

It seems `gform_other_choice_value` does not work the way some of the other Gravity Forms filters work in that adding the form ID and field ID does not target the specific field, such as for field number 142 on form number 27  - `gform_other_choice_value_27_142`

How the form field currently looks
[image]

What I need

[image]

The Gravity Forms documentation (https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_other_choice_value/) shows how to change "Other" wording for all forms, but not a specific field on a specific form.

I need to target a specific field on a specific form, because I will have multiple fields of this type within this single form, as well as many different forms that use "Other" throughout the website.

(Ultimately, I would also like the "Other" field to be the first option, rather than the last, but that's the next step after this - [Make "Other" the first option for a radio button field in Gravity Forms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367247/make-other-the-first-option-for-a-radio-button-field-in-gravity-forms))

Comment: I am not much of a dev, so specific code examples will help much more than replies discussing general concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is the field which contains the form ID to which it belongs and its own ID so you can target a specific form/field like so:

```php
add_filter( 'gform_other_choice_value', function( $placeholder, $field ) {
    // Update "123" to your form ID and "4" to your field ID.
    if ( $field->formId == 123 && $field->id == 4 ) {
        $placeholder = 'Your custom placeholder';
    }
    return $placeholder;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks! This works as expected. Also, tested to make sure it does work with multiple fields on the same form.